# Create new Element with reloading a JS Script

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to implement a jupyter notebook on my flask website with https://github.com/minrk/thebelab.

I have a button, which should create a new cell.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/thebelab@latest"></script>


        <div id="cells">
            <pre id="cell" data-executable="true" data-language="python"></pre>
        </div>

        <button onclick="newCell()">New Cell</button>

        <script>
            function newCell() {

                var pre_cell = document.createElement("pre");

                var attr_id = document.createAttribute("id");
                attr_id.value = "cell";
                pre_cell.setAttributeNode(attr_id);

                var attr_data_executable = document.createAttribute("data-executable");
                attr_data_executable.value = "true";
                pre_cell.setAttributeNode(attr_data_executable);

                var attr_data_language = document.createAttribute("data-language");
                attr_data_language.value = "python";
                pre_cell.setAttributeNode(attr_data_language);

                var element = document.getElementById("cells");
                element.appendChild(pre_cell);            
            }
        </script>
```

The target is to create a new

```
 <pre id="cell" data-executable="true" data-language="python"></pre>
```

in the `cells` div

But I think I need to reload the page to see the cells. The pre tags are adding to the page, but with out the jupyter cell function. Its only a empty pre tag.

How can this solved?

Comment: id attribute values have to be **unique** throughout a page

Comment: also there's absolutely no need to do all that `createAttribute()` work. You can just write `pre_cell.id="something"`, `pre_cell.setAttribute("data-executable", "true")`, etc

Comment: I have change the pre_cell id in the function to something, so I have now the pre tag with id=cell, and the second (should create trough onclick) id="cell2), but its not working